# Why is [bitnami/minio] persistence.mountPath not respected?

Tags: bitnami, minio

I'm using the bitnami/minio helm chart, and I'm trying to configure minio to write to a NFS backed PV. The path specified by persistence.mountPath is created in the pod and successfully mounted to the NFS share.

However, even though I'm setting persistence.mountPath, minio is still writing to /data (the default location) inside the minio pod. When I check the deployed deployment yaml, the mountPath is set correctly to persistence.mountPath.

```
volumeMounts:
   - name: data
     mountPath: /my-data
```

The directory /my-data is created in the pod and is successfully bound to the nfs share.

However, minio still creates buckets in /data despite the fact that I don't see /data anywhere in my deployed yaml.

To Reproduce:

- Override persistence.mountPath
- Deploy chart
- Create bucket
- Exec into minio pod and see where the bucket was created. It is created in /data, not persistence.mountPath.

Expected behavior:
Buckets should be created in persistence.mountPath.

Why is minio still writing to /data? Have I misunderstood the intention of persistence.mountPath?

Answer (score 1):

I figure this out. I left the persistence.mountPath as default (/data), then I had to change the runAs user and group to 1000 (ubuntu).

```
podSecurityContext:
    fsGroup: 1000
containerSecurityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
```

And finally I had to change the owner of the NFS directory to ubuntu.